# The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install dnsutils' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: docker

Trying to install dnsutils during a docker build.

Dockerfile:

```sh
# Dockerfile - this is a comment. Delete me if you want.

FROM python:2.7

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install dnsutils

CMD ["python","unitTest.py"]
```

Output:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.

The command `/bin/sh -c apt-get install dnsutils` returned a non-zero code: 1
```

How can I install dig in image without above error?

Answer (score 2):

Add `-y` for it to auto accept & stay non-interactive -

```
RUN apt-get install -y dnsutils
```

Answer (score 1):

Some packages ask for confirmation when installing them.

Thats why you get: "Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort"

Add '-y' to `apt-get install`:

```
RUN apt-get install dnsutils -y
```